# Refresh JTree(TreeNode) without TreeModel

Tags: java, swing, jtree

In my Java application, I've already got data in a tree-like structure. therefore it was the easiest way to have each class representing a "node" implement the TreeNode interface.

```
public class GPXObject implements TreeNode {
    public Enumeration<TreeNode> children() {}
    public boolean getAllowsChildren() {}
    public TreeNode getChildAt(int childIndex) {}
    public int getChildCount() {}
    public int getIndex(TreeNode node) {}
    public boolean isLeaf() {}
}
```

the tree is instantiated using the JTree(TreeNode) constructor:

```
GPXObject gpxRoot = new GPXObject();
gpxRoot.add(....) // add child nodes & subtrees ....
JTree tree = new JTree(gpxRoot);
```

now, I can't find a way to refresh the tree when nodes are added via external data sources since

- there is no custom TreeModel

- there is no tree.getModel.reload() method

- there are no DefaultMutableTreeNodes

did I get the purpose of JTree(TreeNode) wrong?
do I have to implement a custom TreeModel anyway?

tnx

Comment: While it might seem like a bad idea, you should keep the UI/TreeModel separate from your data model, this allows you to manage the data model independently. You would then wrap this around the TreeModel/TreeNode structure.  This way, when you update the data model, you would generate some kind of notification when you could use to update the state of the `TreeModel`.  You've also hit one of the bug-bears of `JTree`, the nodes are separated from the model, when they should be related to it, so you can access the model from a node when you need to update something :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for this information. Looks like I have to extend DefaultTreeModel to be able to use reload().

Comment: I'd be looking at `insertNodeInto`, `nodeChanged`, `nodesWereInserted`, `nodesWereRemoved` before running off to `reload`, this will generate smaller change requests which will be efficient